# How to use a firebase link in a playlist with just_audio

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, firebase-storage, just-audio

I'm a beginner on Flutter. I'm currently trying to add audio on my application and I use just_audio for it. This is working well but I have trouble to play audio from a firebase. This is the code I take from the example which is working :

```
final _playlist = ConcatenatingAudioSource(children: [
    AudioSource.uri(
      Uri.parse(
          "https://s3.amazonaws.com/scifri-episodes/scifri20181123-episode.mp3"),
      tag: AudioMetadata(
        album: "Science Friday",
        title: "A Salute To Head-Scratching Science",
      ),
    ),
    AudioSource.uri(
      Uri.parse("https://s3.amazonaws.com/scifri-segments/scifri201711241.mp3"),
      tag: AudioMetadata(
        album: "Science Friday",
        title: "From Cat Rheology To Operatic Incompetence",
      ),
    ),
    AudioSource.uri(
      Uri.parse("asset:///audio/nature.mp3"),
      tag: AudioMetadata(
        album: "Public Domain",
        title: "Nature Sounds",
      ),
    ),
  ]);
```

When I try to replace the actual link with one from my firebase, this isn't working.

My link from the firebase is :

https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/milo-5876c.appspot.com/o/audio%2FAsni%C3%A8res-sur-V%C3%A8gre%2FFresque1%2Fenfer1.mp3?alt=media&token=d713bdd8-5188-4d5a-87e6-4e67f1725057

I don't understand because it was working with another plugin but I need to use just_audio for others features.

Thanks a lot,

Cinqprien

Answer (score 0):

Your server (i.e. firebase storage) is configured with a Content-Type header that of `audio/mpeg` but your actual audio file is an `mp4` file. It should work if you use `audio/mp4` and maybe also `video/mp4`.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer and for the plugin btw it's great. I didn't use your solution but just upload the audio in m4a and it's working so I guess it's good.